# Reverse Number in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int ans = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            int val = x % 10;
            int tmp = ans;
            ans = ans * 10 + val;
            if ((ans - val) / 10 != tmp) {
                return 0;
            }
            x /= 10;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

I came about with this code to solve the reverse number problem. If I do it on paper and with a negative number as an input, I get different result. I believe it has to do with how java handles Mod. Please if someone can explain this case.

-429 on paper gives me 186 where as on computer -924 why?

Comment: Did you step through it line by line with a debugger to see where your results in the code and paper differ? That's how you solve questions like this.

Comment: The reverse of **-429** is **186**?

Answer (score 0):

It loops 3 times:

first loop:

```
 int ans = 0;
 while (x != 0) {                     //x = -429
     int val = x % 10;                //val = -9
     int tmp = ans;                   //tmp = 0
     ans = ans * 10 + val;            //ans = -9
     if ((ans - val) / 10 != tmp) {   //false
         return 0;
     }
     x /= 10;                         //x=-42
 }
```

second loop:

```
 int ans = 0;
 while (x != 0) {                     //x = -42
     int val = x % 10;                //val = -2
     int tmp = ans;                   //tmp = -9
     ans = ans * 10 + val;            //ans = -92
     if ((ans - val) / 10 != tmp) {   //false
         return 0;
     }
     x /= 10;                         //x = -4
 }
```

third loop:

```
 int ans = 0;
 while (x != 0) {                     //x = -4
     int val = x % 10;                //val = -4
     int tmp = ans;                   //tmp = -92
     ans = ans * 10 + val;            //ans = -924
     if ((ans - val) / 10 != tmp) {   //false
         return 0;
     }
     x /= 10;                         //x = 0
 }

return -924
```